# Is it possible to have .net console application that embed another executable file?

Tags: vb.net, command-line-interface

I have a single command line windows executable that has many options built into this exe file.

Eg:

(It can take screenshot)

```
ToolGo.exe printscreen c:\temp\filename.jpg yyyymmdd
```

(It can show up)

```
ToolGo.exe showIP machineA
```

I want to write another command line application, possibly in .net , where it can embed/build a wrapper around this `ToolGo.exe` file into my application without the user be able to use the `ToolGo.exe`, and also users can only access one function of this main exe file.

In the example I want this other tool to access only the `print screen` function in this new exe file.

The new application will have this:

```
Tool2go.exe printscreen c:\temp\filename.jpg yyyymmdd
```

But if someone types the following, it will not work:

```
Tool2go.exe showIP machineA
```

Or

```
ToolGo.exe showIP machineA
```

Any ideas how I can write this code to do this in a .net command line application?

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-part question, so I'll just give the main part of the issue as the answer with suggestions on handling the rest.

You can embed a .exe into your program by clicking on Properties and navigating the the Resources section, and adding that .exe to it.

After that, it's just a matter of extracting it locally so you can pass your commands to it, and handle it's responses. (I'm not really aware of any way to do so w/out first extracting the. exe; the .exe itself needs to run somehow after all).

To extract the embedded .exe, you do this:

```
' Extract the MyProgram resource (i.e. your .exe)
Dim b() As Byte = My.Resources.MyProgram

' Write it to the user's Temp folder
File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%\MyProgram.exe"), b)
```

By extracting it to the user's Temp folder, you can pass it your commands, and since it's 'out of sight' the user probably won't even know it's there to directly use it themselves, unless they're a bit more advanced and visit their Temp folder often. You can slightly help to avoid this, but extracting the .exe when your program starts, and then deleting it when it exits, so it only exists on the user's system while your program is running.

As far as what the user can and cannot type in order to pass to the program, you can simply handle the filtering with your program; since your program is the one passing the commands to the .exe, just don't pass any commands that you don't allowed, and pass the ones you do want allowed.